# Classical and Modern Zariski Topologies

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the connection between the "classical" Zariski topology on a variety, that is closed sets defined as the vanishing set of some ideal, $V(A)$, and the "modern" topology on the prime spectrum, that is closed sets defined as the set of all primes containing some ideal, again denoted $V(A)$. By the nullstellensatz, given any ideal $A$, the set of maximal ideals containing $A$ can be identified precisely with the vanishing set of A, in the classical sense. But in the new topology, we must also include the non-maximal primes containing $A$. My question is, can we describe such new primes which must be introduced explicitly? In reading Mumford, in the case of $k[X,Y]$ at least, it is stated that closed sets in Spec can be formed by taking finitely many closed points and irreducible curves along with their generic points. But then given an irreducible curve in the old topology, considering it as composed of maximal ideals, do we need only to add a generic point to make it closed in the new topology? Thanks!

Comment: There's only one Zariski topology. The Zariski *closure* of an ideal is the set of primes containing it. The Zariski closure of a subset of affine space is the vanishing set of the closure of its corresponding ideal in the coordinate ring.

Comment: The answer is: soberfication. The sobrefication of the maximal spectrum is the prime spectrum (for reduced $k$-algebras of finite type). See Wedhorn and Görtz book (the first chapter is basically devoted to this equivalence). Furthermore you can see the Zariski topology (for primes) as the zeroes of an element $f \in A$, by evaluating $f(\mathfrak{p})$ as the image of $f$ in composition $A \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{p} \rightarrow \kappa (\mathfrak{p})$ .

Comment: @user40276: More generally, for any ring, the soberification of the maximal spectrum is the the space of those prime ideals which are an intersection of maximal ideals. See *Almost maximal ideals* by Johnstone (1983).

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt Yes, I know. This is more or less a consequence of Nullstellensatz (as stated in Wedhorn and Görtz)

Answer (score 0):

Let $V\subseteq \mathbb{A}^n_k$ is a variety over a field $k$ ("classical geometry"). The prime spectrum of the coordinate ring of $V$ will be a larger topological space. More specifically, define $\tau(V)$ to be the collection of all closed irreducible subsets of $V$. This way there is a natural embedding $V\to \tau(V)$, and $\tau(V)$ is homeomorphic to the prime spectrum of its coordinate ring. Thus, the "modern geometry" includes also the closed irreducible subsets together with the original points of $V$.

Comment: This makes sense I think, but how exactly does the homeomorphism you mention work?

Comment: @kfried For a point $p\in V$, send $p$ to $\overline{\{ p\}}$, the closure of $p$. Since $\{p\}$ is irreducible, its closure is irreducible as well.

Comment: Do you mean $p \in \tau (V)$? Then $p$ is the vanishing set of some prime ideal $P$ in the coordinate ring, so it is already closed correct? I think I am missing something.